# Same Origin Policy Problem using WFS-T with Geoserver & OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t, openlayers, cors

I'm trying to use a WFS-T Service to insert a simple Point from OpenLayers 3 into Geoserver in a VirtualBox (test environment). There is always the same error message:

```
    Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8383 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. at http://HOST_IP:8082/geoserver/test/wfs
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://HOST_IP:8082/geoserver/test/wfs. Origin http://localhost:8383 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (13:29:51:925 | error, javascript) at resources/webappv1.html
```

I took the issue and tried to solve it with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

A ProxyPass (like http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html)  would be for security reason only a bad alternative.

I found a solution on the Geoserver Mailing Archive by Dusan Fedorcak (Search for [Geoserver-users] CORS for jetty 6.1.8 (Geoserver 2.x)) and tried to manage it , but it is still not working.

Where do I go wrong? 
Or is there an other workflow to make a post Request with OL3?

Here my versions:

- OpenLayers 3
- Geosever 2.4.4 runs on VirtualBox 4.3.10 with OSGeo Live7.9 installation
- Jetty 6.1.8
- PostGIS 2.1.1

Here my code:

```
var xmlData =
            +'< wfs:Transaction\n'
            + 'service = "WFS"\n'
            + 'version = "1.0.0"\n'
            + 'xmlns:wfs = "http://www.opengis.net/wfs"\n'
            + 'xmlns:gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml"\n'
            + 'xmlns:test = "http://test.org"\n'
            + 'xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \n'
            + 'xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.opengis.net/wfs \n'
            + 'http://HOST_IP:8082/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd \n'
            + 'http://test.org/ \n' 
            + 'http://HOST_IP:8082/geoserver/test/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?

typename=test:user_poi">\n'
            + '< wfs:Insert >\n'
            + '< test:user_poi >\n'
            + '< test:gid >' + gid + '< /test:gid>\n'
            + '< test:id >' + id + '< /test:id>\n'
            + '< test:tid >' + id + '< /test:tid>\n'
            + '< test:auid >' + auid + '< /test:auid>\n'
            + '< test:mdid >' + mdid + '< /test:mdid>\n'
            + '< test:text >' + text + '< /test:text>\n'
            + '< test:the_geom >\n'
            + '< gml:Point srsDimension = "2" srsName = "urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3857" \n'
            + '< gml:coordinates decimal = "." cs = "," ts = " " >' + lat + ',' + long + '< /gml:coordinates>\n'
            + '< /gml:Point>\n'
            + '< /test:the_geom>\n'
            + '< /test:user_poi>\n'
            + '< /wfs:Insert>\n'
            + '< /wfs:Transaction>\n';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: wfsurl,
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        data: xmlData,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        username: 'user',
        password: 'user',
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
        },
        error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue with OpenLayers 3/WFS/CORS?  Did you notice this issue in OpenLayers 2.X?

Comment: No it is still not working. Which issue with OL 2.X do you mean?